# How to correctly reset graph and variables after Restoring Trained Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, scope, restore

I found the following code and tried to implement a `Saver()` for confirming the trained model can in fact be loaded an used but seems some variables or something isn't getting restored correctly (suspect variable scope items).

The code in question checks if the model exists, if the model doesn't exist, it will train and save the model, if the model exists, it will try to restore the model then run the prediction on test data. Upon first training, the prediction test data works fine, but subsequent runs when running and loading the trained model, the test data predictions fail (gives garbled data [date numbers/format]).

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import random
import json
import os
import time

from faker import Faker
import babel
from babel.dates import format_date

import tensorflow as tf

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Embedding

import tensorflow.contrib.legacy_seq2seq as seq2seq

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

NUMBER_OF_EPOCHS = 10
BATCH_SIZE = 128
NUMBER_OF_NODES = 32
EMBEDDED_SIZE = 10

fake = Faker()
fake.seed(42)
random.seed(42)

_modelPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "\Model\date_model.ckpt" 

tf.reset_default_graph()

inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None, 29), 'inputs')
outputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None, None), 'output')
targets = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None, None), 'targets')

FORMATS = ['short',
           'medium',
           'long',
           'full',
           'd MMM YYY',
           'd MMMM YYY',
           'dd MMM YYY',
           'd MMM, YYY',
           'd MMMM, YYY',
           'dd, MMM YYY',
           'd MM YY',
           'd MMMM YYY',
           'MMMM d YYY',
           'MMMM d, YYY',
           'dd.MM.YY',
           ]

# change this if you want it to work with only a single language
LOCALES = babel.localedata.locale_identifiers()
LOCALES = [lang for lang in LOCALES if 'en' in str(lang)]

def create_date():
    """
        Creates some fake dates 
        :returns: tuple containing 
                  1. human formatted string
                  2. machine formatted string
                  3. date object.
    """
    dt = fake.date_object()

    try:
        human = format_date(dt, format=random.choice(FORMATS), locale=random.choice(LOCALES))

        case_change = random.randint(0,3) # 1/2 chance of case change
        if case_change == 1:
            human = human.upper()
        elif case_change == 2:
            human = human.lower()

        machine = dt.isoformat()
    except AttributeError as e:
        return None, None, None

    return human, machine #, dt

data = [create_date() for _ in range(50000)]

x = [x for x, y in data]
y = [y for x, y in data]

u_characters = set(' '.join(x))
char2numX = dict(zip(u_characters, range(len(u_characters))))

u_characters = set(' '.join(y))
char2numY = dict(zip(u_characters, range(len(u_characters))))

char2numX['<PAD>'] = len(char2numX)
num2charX = dict(zip(char2numX.values(), char2numX.keys()))
max_len = max([len(date) for date in x])

x = [[char2numX['<PAD>']]*(max_len - len(date)) +[char2numX[x_] for x_ in date] for date in x]
print(''.join([num2charX[x_] for x_ in x[4]]))
x = np.array(x)

char2numY['<GO>'] = len(char2numY)
num2charY = dict(zip(char2numY.values(), char2numY.keys()))

y = [[char2numY['<GO>']] + [char2numY[y_] for y_ in date] for date in y]
print(''.join([num2charY[y_] for y_ in y[4]]))
y = np.array(y)

x_seq_length = len(x[0])
y_seq_length = len(y[0])- 1

print(x_seq_length)

def batch_data(x, y, BATCH_SIZE):
    shuffle = np.random.permutation(len(x))
    start = 0
#     from IPython.core.debugger import Tracer; Tracer()()
    x = x[shuffle]
    y = y[shuffle]
    while start + BATCH_SIZE <= len(x):
        yield x[start:start+BATCH_SIZE], y[start:start+BATCH_SIZE]
        start += BATCH_SIZE

# Embedding layers
input_embedding = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((len(char2numX), EMBEDDED_SIZE), -1.0, 1.0), name='enc_embedding')
output_embedding = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((len(char2numY), EMBEDDED_SIZE), -1.0, 1.0), name='dec_embedding')

date_input_embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(input_embedding, inputs)
date_output_embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(output_embedding, outputs)

with tf.variable_scope("encoding") as encoding_scope:
    lstm_enc = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(NUMBER_OF_NODES)
    _, last_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_enc, inputs=date_input_embed, dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.variable_scope("decoding") as decoding_scope:
    lstm_dec = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(NUMBER_OF_NODES)
    dec_outputs, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_dec, inputs=date_output_embed, initial_state=last_state)

#connect outputs to 
logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(dec_outputs, num_outputs=len(char2numY), activation_fn=None) 

with tf.name_scope("optimization"):
    # Loss function
    loss = tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss(logits, targets, tf.ones([BATCH_SIZE, y_seq_length]))
    # Optimizer
    optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(1e-3).minimize(loss)

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope=None)) # Add ops to save and restore all the variables.

sess = tf.Session() 
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

if os.path.isfile(_modelPath + ".index"):

    saver.restore(sess, _modelPath) #Yes, no need to add ".index"
    print('Done Restoring Model.')


else:

    print('Traning Model.')
    for epoch_i in range(NUMBER_OF_EPOCHS):

        for batch_i, (source_batch, target_batch) in enumerate(batch_data(X_train, Y_train, BATCH_SIZE)):
            _, batch_loss, batch_logits = sess.run([optimizer, loss, logits], feed_dict = {inputs: source_batch, outputs: target_batch[:, :-1], targets: target_batch[:, 1:]})

        accuracy = np.mean(batch_logits.argmax(axis=-1) == target_batch[:,1:])
        print('Epoch {:3} Loss: {:>6.3f} Accuracy: {:>6.4f}'.format(epoch_i, batch_loss, accuracy))

    # Save the variables to disk.
    save_path = saver.save(sess, _modelPath)
    print("Retraining Done. Updated model saved in file: %s" % save_path + ' ' + os.path.abspath(save_path))

#Setup test batches
source_batch, target_batch =  next(batch_data(X_test, Y_test, BATCH_SIZE))

print("{} {} total length:{}".format(source_batch[0], target_batch[0], len(source_batch)))

print(char2numY['<GO>'])

dec_input = np.zeros((len(source_batch), 1)) + char2numY['<GO>']

for i in range(y_seq_length):
    batch_logits = sess.run(logits, feed_dict = {inputs: source_batch,  outputs: dec_input})
    prediction = batch_logits[:,-1].argmax(axis=-1)
    dec_input = np.hstack([dec_input, prediction[:,None]])

print('Accuracy on test set is: {:>6.3f}'.format(np.mean(dec_input == target_batch)))

num_preds = 2
source_chars = [[num2charX[x_index] for x_index in sent if num2charX[x_index]!="<PAD>"] for sent in source_batch[:num_preds]]
dest_chars = [[num2charY[y_index] for y_index in sent] for sent in dec_input[:num_preds, 1:]]

for date_in, date_out in zip(source_chars, dest_chars):
    print(''.join(date_in)+' => '+''.join(date_out))
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. The issue was that my lexicon (num and char lookups) were randomized upon each run and the lookups from the trained model to subsequent runs were different. So I needed to pickle these lookups when the model is trained, they are a given set of values and these values need to be associated with the trained model.

So, when I initially train the model, I needed to do this to save the lookups:

```
with open(_picklePath,'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump([char2numX, num2charX, char2numY, num2charY],f)
```

Then when running again to predict, I needed to reload these lookups:

```
with open(_picklePath,'rb') as f:
    [char2numX, num2charX, char2numY, num2charY] = pickle.load(f)
```

Of course I needed to rearrange my original code to accommodate/accomplish this. Now the question is, could the pickling be accomplished with the "Saver" object? If so, how?